# Unresolved reference:test in KoinTest

Tags: android, android-testing, koin

I'm trying to do some test with Koin, but I'm getting the "Unresolved reference:KoinTest' howeber, seems  that is doing the imports correctly, because I can't see any error in the code. Is only when I try to run the test.

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project and reinit android studio, but still the problem

TEST CLASS

```
 import org.junit.After
    import org.junit.Before
    import org.junit.Test
    import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
    import org.koin.core.context.stopKoin
    import org.koin.test.KoinTest
    import salva.perez.cabify.di.applicationModule
    import org.koin.test.inject
    class VoucherPresenterTest : KoinTest {

        private val presenter: VoucherContract.Presenter by inject()


        @Before
        fun before() {
            startKoin {
                modules(applicationModule)
            }
        }

        @After
        fun after() {
            stopKoin()
        }

        @Test
        fun testInitViewCorrectly() {
            ...
        }
    }
```

GRADLE

```
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1'
```

Comment: added `repositories {
 jcenter()    
}`?

Comment: You mean in project build.gradle. I have jcenter: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"  
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

Comment: add `'org.koin:koin-core:2.0.1'`

Comment: Nothing. I did a clean and rebuilt. Same error Unresolved reference:test and Unresolved reference:KointTest

Comment: I found the problem. Was that was running in wrong test folder

Answer (score 9):

Consider using `androidTestImplementation` if you want to use it in your `androidTest` and `debugImplementation` if you want to use it in `unitTest` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being so late(just 2 years late) but if there is someone that is still looking for this solution.. You have to put manually the import -> import org.koin.test.inject , to Android recognize the KoinTest interface.

Comment: This was the answer in the right direction though not completely accurate. In my case, I had to use import org.koin.test.* for the error to stop showing. If anyone knows the correct package, they can edit the answer above.